# How to create entity inheritance in room database?

Tags: java, android, android-room

Good morning ,I was using SQLite database then I've changed to Room. I have a superclass "Person" and two subclasses "Femme" and "Enfant".
How can I create the tables to the two subclasses in Room .

Person.java

```
public class Personne {

private  int idP;
private String nom,prenom;
private int age, poids;


public Personne(String nom, String prenom, int age, int poids) {

    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.age = age;
    this.poids = poids;

}

public Personne(String nom, String prenom) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;

}
```

Femme.java

```
  public class Femme extends Personne { 

   private String pseudo,mdp,grpSang;

public Femme(String nom, String prenom, int age, int poid, String pseudo, 
 String mdp, String grpSang) {
    super(nom, prenom, age, poid);
    this.pseudo = pseudo;
    this.mdp = mdp;
    this.grpSang = grpSang;
}
}
```

Enfant.java

```
 public class Enfant extends Personne {

     private float taille;
     private Sexe sexe;
      private Date DN;

public Enfant(String nom, String prenom, int age, int poid, int taille, 
 Sexe sexe) {
    super(nom, prenom, age, poid);
    this.taille = taille;
    this.sexe = sexe;
}
}
```

Comment: You mean create kind of view displaying two tables at once?

Comment: No two diffrent table , but my problem is how to create for example the table "Enfant" and inherit all the attribute

Answer (score 0):

Good Afternoon, mate. Let's start creating two variables in Persoone object. Your new `Personne.java` will look like below:

```
@Entity (tableName = "yourPersonneTableName")
public class Personne {

@PrimaryKey
private  int idP;
private String nom,prenom;
private int age, poids;
@Ignore
private List<Femme> femmeList;
@Ignore
private List<Enfant> enfant;

// setters and getters here

}
```

In the above code block, I added the list of your two subclasses but @Ignore them. Because I won't need them but. You can actually remove them.

Let's go to your subclasses.

```
@Entity (tableName = "yourEnfantTableName")
public class Enfant{

        @PrimaryKey
        private long newId;
        // you can have newId here or change one of your original parameters into PrimaryKey
        private int idP;
        // you can manipulate through this id of your Personne table there.
        private float taille;
        private Sexe sexe;
        private Date DN;
        // setters and getters here
    }

@Entity (tableName = "yourFemmeTableName")
public class Femme{ 
    @PrimaryKey
    private long newId
    // you can have newId here or your can change one of your parameter into PrimaryKey
    private int idP;
    // you can manipulate through this id of your Personne table there.
    private String pseudo,mdp,grpSang;
```

}

That's it. You can add data into all of those tables partly. But you can use them what you want through `idP`.

Another type is using @TypeConverters

One example using your Enfant class

```
public class EnfantToStringConverter {

@TypeConverter
public String imageToString(List<Enfant> enfant){
    return new Gson().toJson(enfant);
}

@TypeConverter
public List<ImagesVO> stringToImage(String strGson){
    return new Gson().fromJson(strGson, new TypeToken<List<Enfant>>(){}.getType());
}
```

}

But your Personne.class will be changed a little bit.

Here is your resources.

```
@Entity (tableName = "yourPersonneTableName")
public class Personne {

@PrimaryKey
private  int idP;
private String nom,prenom;
private int age, poids;

@TypeConverters({FemmeToStringConverter.class})
private List<Femme> femmeList;

@TypeConverters({EnfantToStringConverter.class})
private List<Enfant> enfant;

// setters and getters here

}
```

Anyway, you need to read just a little bit here.

[RoomTypeConverter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter)

[RoomTypeConverters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverters)

[Ignore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Ignore)

Comment: I have some question : 1- you didn't use extend why? 2-Why would I use two Ids instead of one ? and how can I insert one Femme into my database ? could you explain for me plz

Comment: Actually, we can use inheritance smoothly in room. So why not? Two ids is not actually two Ids. One is primary key and one is Foreign key of Personne table. Inserting is depend on where you get that data. Where are you getting that data? I mean from Network or from local?

Comment: but you didn't mention the foreign key and also why you didn't extend from Person

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that in cmd.